# How to: await / async in a node.js lambda function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, aws-lambda, async.js

I am trying to create an async lambda function that makes a **http** **Get** call put it's not working correctly and I believe it has to do with it being async.  If I remove **await/async**, and make it synchronous, my function works correctly.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Thank you for your help!

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {

    await setBattery();

    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};

async function setBattery() {
    'use strict';

    const https = require('https');

    const options = {
        hostname: 'testsite.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/proxy/api/setting?EM_OperatingMode=1',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    const req = https.request(options, res => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

        res.on('data', d => {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', error => {
        console.error(error);
    });

    req.end();

}
```

Comment: you haven't wrapped your logic of `setBattery` in a promise.

Comment: ok.  I have not used a promise before.

Comment: async/await are tools that use promises, to understand async/await you need to understand promises. Also, adding async to a function definition changes the return type of that function to a promise, so you'll need to handle that promise. Something like `exports.handler(a, b).then(() => {}).catch(() => {}).finally(() => {})`

Comment: "If I remove await/async, and make it synchronous, my function works correctly." Why do you want it to be async?

Comment: I am trying to add an http get call to our Alexa smart home skill lambda function and most of the code async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According with MDN Web Docs:

> The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which
>   returns an AsyncFunction object. An asynchronous function is a
>   function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, using an
>   ***implicit Promise to return its result***. But the syntax and structure of
>   your code using async functions is much more like using standard
>   synchronous functions.

So, You need to return a `Promise` object in order to be handled by your `async function` (You could also use another promise to handle it), I converted `setBattery` to a normal function and the return of this function is now a promise that will be handled by your handler (`exports.handler`). I haven't tested the code but it should work.

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {

    await setBattery();

    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};

function setBattery() {
    'use strict';

    const https = require('https');

    const options = {
        hostname: 'testsite.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/proxy/api/setting?EM_OperatingMode=1',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    // Return it as a Promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const req = https.request(options, res => {
            console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

            res.on('data', d => {
                process.stdout.write(d);

                // If successful
                resolve(d);
            });
        });

        req.on('error', error => {
            console.error(error);

            // If failed
            reject(error);
        });

        req.end();

    });

}
```